# "900 STRA" License Plate Meaning

Tags: transformers

"900 STRA" seems to be the most common license plate in Transformers.

It is on Bumblebee but I can't determine the meaning.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://tfwiki.net/wiki/License_plate

Comment: It doesn't seem to be all that common, based on the wiki link above

Comment: @Edlothaid ignoring cartoons I can't not find one more common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it was in reference to the house that previously belonged to Michael Bay, that was for sale at the time of production of the movie, on 900 Stradella Road.

> A Bel Air mansion on a site formerly owned by big-budget action movie producer and director Michael Bay has sold for $41 million. The modernist manse originally designed by Jack Warner at **900 Stradella Road** underwent a major renovation following Bay’s 2014 sale that nearly doubled its footprint, from just under 8,000 square feet to 15,000 square feet, according to the Los Angeles Times. The home was listed for $45 million. Bay sold it in 2014 for just under $12 million.
>
> <sub>[Spec home on site of Michael Bay’s former manse sells for $41M](https://therealdeal.com/la/2017/12/20/spec-home-on-site-of-michael-bays-former-manse-sells-for-41m/)</sub>

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Is there some relevant info in the article you linked to? If so, you should ideally copy and paste (or upload) anything relevant from the article into your answer, so that it'll remain part of the answer even if the link goes down for any reason.

Answer (score 2):

Within the film universe it was simply the licence plate of the vehicle that he scanned in the tunnel.

Out-of-universe, no specific meaning seems to have been given but the TRA suffix may relate to "**TRA**nsformer". Note that in his 'junker' form his plate suffix was 489-PCE (presumably as in PieCE of shit)

Comment: @Buzz first of all, *The Last Knight* establishes that there have been Transformers on Earth since the days of King Arthur, and in any event there are still 1974 Camaros around today. There are still a few *Model T Fords* on the road, a '74 Camaro is not hard to find at all.

Comment: @Buzz https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/l-Used-1974-Chevrolet-Camaro-c3673

Comment: @RobertColumbia Even before that, *Revenge of the Fallen* establishes that there have been Transformers on Earth since 17,000 BC. However, Buzz was talking about Transformers in real life being an IP. His comment in full context should be read "There were no transformers (shows) in 1974".

Comment: I have posted this as an answer but I think this not quite right https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Mighty_Stra

Comment: @RobertColumbia Buzz is referencing the 1974 animated series Valorum referenced in his answer. Not the Camaro.

Comment: @William - Looks like we were both wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

This took some digging but I think it fairly obviously once I found it that 900 STRA likely refers to [Mighty Stra](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Mighty_Stra)(later renamed to mighty strike).  I am not sure what the 900 stands for but the STRA seems more then a coincidence.

[image]

Comment: *" once I found it that 900 STRA refers to Mighty Stra"*. Can you provide any evidence to back up this bold claim and/or that this isn't simply a coincidence?

Comment: @Valorum Nothing more then forums.  Much stronger argument then it standing for S**TRA** Transformers in my opinion.  I rephrased the sentence to now include likely.